Using Power Automate to copy file with metadata from one site to another
I have a SharePoint library with columns. One of those columns is a multi-choice column.
When a file is uploaded in this library, and the columns are filled in, i want to copy this file and its exact columns to another site.
Most goes well, but i'm having problems copying the content of the multi-choice columns. I already did this with a list, using an array, but the update file properties doesn't seem to give me the possibility using an array to fill in multiple choices at once.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Are you using "Update file properties" action to make it? However, the "Update file properties" action does not support multi-choice columns. As a workaround, you can use the "Send an HTTP request to SharePoint" action to update the multi-choice column.
Please note that the "Send an HTTP request to SharePoint" action requires the "Full Control" permission level on the destination site.

I am indeed using update file properties. Could you please try to explain how i use "send an http request" to fix this issue?
